What is the specific thing that Peter does not know?
While he is motivating Miles, Lyla is speaking to Peter on comms:

LYLA (into comms): We got your location Peter. Sit tight,  we’re on
the way.
PETER: Wait wait, no no no! You don’t have my location, over!

Miguel is flying:

Miguel (into comms): Send Everyone.
PETER: Miles I didn’t know, I promise you.

What is the specific thing that Peter does not know?

From the shooting script:

PETER
who can’t take the disappointment in Miles’ gaze --
PETER
Miles I didn’t know, I promise you.
Please, let’s talk about this.

What is implied was that Peter didn't realize that Lyla would track his position to find Miles. He's apologizing for that, and also assuring Miles that he didn't intentionally betray him.
